# PCYACC expect keyword equivalent

Tags: bison, yacc, lalr

Is there a keyword in PCYACC which is equivalent to BISON's [expect declaration](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Expect-Decl.html):

```
%expect NUMBER
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any corresponding command-line option or language feature in the [PCYACC Program Manual](http://www.abxsoft.com/pcyacc.htm).

Comment: Can we give precedence to a rule(not an operator)?